# $\infty$-norm of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, jacobian, condition-number

While reading the book *Numerical Linear Algebra* by Trefethen & Bau, I came across the following example.

---

[image: Example from Trefethen & Bau]

---

The authors indicate that $\|J\|_{\infty} = 2$. However, if I recall the definition of $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ correctly, $$\left\| \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \right\|_{\infty} = \max(\|1\|, \|{-1}\|)$$ which is obviously $1$.
Is this just a typo (the argument still holds if $\|J\|_{\infty} = 1$) or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: $\|{-1}\|$? Why take the norm of a real?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the subordinate matrix infinity norm defined as:

$$\|A\|_{\infty} =\max_{1 \leq i \leq m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|,$$
for the matrix $$A=\left(
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
      \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      a_{m1}&\cdots&a_{mn}
    \end{array}
\right). $$

Comment: Why are we using the subordinate matrix infinity norm, instead of the vector infinity norm?

Comment: Is it because the Jacobian is a $1 \times 2$ matrix, and not a vector?

Answer (score -2):

So I think if J is not a matrix but a vector, we have
∥J∥∞ = (|1|^∞+|-1|^∞)^(1/∞) = 2^(1/∞) = 1.
Also I do a matlab simulation and the result is 1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7M1h.png)

So I doubt there is a typo.